# Collision Detection in processing

Tags: java, processing

I have a processing program with shapes that move across the screen, and lose health when they collide.  Like a battle.  But the collision detection only works on one set of colliding units at a time.  If a battle is happening at a point on the screen, other battles won't happen until that one finishes.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < friendlies.size(); j++){
      if(checkCollision(friendlies.get(j),enemies.get(i))){
        if(ttime == 0){
          ttime = millis();
        }
        if((millis()-ttime)>1000){
          if(enemies.get(i).getXSpeed()==0 && enemies.get(i).getYSpeed()==0){
          enemies.get(i).attackfriendly(friendlies.get(j));}
          if(friendlies.get(j).getXSpeed()==0 && friendlies.get(j).getYSpeed()==0){
          friendlies.get(j).attackenemy(enemies.get(i));
          }
          ttime=0;
        }
      }

    }
  }




boolean checkCollision(friendlyUnit f, enemyUnit e){
  if(Math.abs(f.getX()-e.getX()) < 21 && Math.abs(f.getY()-e.getY()) < 21){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}


  void attackenemy(enemyUnit e){
    int damage=0;
    ArrayList<friendlyUnit>friendnear = new ArrayList<friendlyUnit>();
    for (int i=0; i< friendlies.size(); i++){
      if ((checkCollision(friendlies.get(i),e))&& friendlies.get(i).isAlive()){
        friendnear.add(friendlies.get(i));
      }
    }
    for (int j=0; j<friendnear.size();j++){
      damage=damage+friendnear.get(j).getAttack();
    }
    e.changeHealth(damage);
  }
```

enemies and friendlies are arrays of enemy and friendly shapes.  The ttime stuff is a timer.  getX and getY return X and Y coorinates.

Comment: Can you post your code here as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Got the wrong link, my bad.

Comment: Most people won't click links like that. You'll have much better luck posting the code here as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does your `attackfriendly()` method do? As it is, you would have to use threading so that this method can run in one thread and the collision checking could continue in the main thread. Alternatively you would have to restructure your code in some way.

Comment: We haven't learned anything about threading yet.  Should I give up on getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ttime is a global and is getting checked/reset for all friendly/enemy interactions, rather than each interaction having it's own ttime. Does only 1 attack happen about every second? You need to have an array of ttimes so that a timer is only associated with one interaction, which means an array/ArrayList of size (enemies.size()*friendlies.size()), one for each interaction.